# Not able to use spring dependency injection across various classes for TestNG using java annotations(JSR 330 Standard Annotations)

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, jsr330

I have a service which I am trying to inject across various classes in my tests but I am getting its instance as null.

My config interface:

```
MyService.java

public interface MyService {

    public String getHostUri();

}
```

My implementation class of this interface: <kbd>MyServiceImpl.java</kbd>

```
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {

    private static final String BASE_HOST_URI_CONFIG = "localhost:4444";

    @Override
    public String getHostUri() {
        return BASE_HOST_URI_CONFIG;
    }
```

My Spring configuration class with the bean:

```
@Configuration

public class AutomationSpringConfig {

    @Bean
    public MyService getMyService(){
        return new MyServiceImpl();
    }

}
```

My testNG class:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes=AutomationSpringConfig.class ,loader =AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)

public class BasicAutomatedTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(BasicAutomatedTest.class);

    @Inject
    private MyService myService;


    @Test
    public void basicTest {
        Setup setup = new Setup();
        LOGGER.info(myService.getHostUri());
        LOGGER.info(setup.myService.getHostUri());

    }
}
```

My helper class in which I am not able to get the injection:

```
public class Setup {

  @Inject

  public MyService myService;

}
```

So when I try to get the hostUri via the setup object in the BasicAutomatedTest's basicTest method I get a NullPointerException.
So I am not able to inject the MyService bean in the Setup class.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use annotations you need to specify that behaviour in your beans XML configuration file. Something like this:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="your.base.package"/>
<context:annotation-config/>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I am just using Java based annotations and not XML config so can you specify in terms of annotations.